# Convert pandas dataframe column containing Excel general numbers into datetime object

Tags: excel, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I constructed from pulling data from SQL using pd.read_sql_query(). I have one column that has dates but in excel general number format. How do convert this column into datetime object.

I can convert one value with the xlrd library but looking for the best way to convert the entire column.
datetime_value = datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(42369, 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to apply a lambda function performing that operation to every entry in a column:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
from datetime import datetime

# Create dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": [42369, 42370, 42371, 42372]
    })
print df.to_string()

# Convert values into a new column named "converted"
df["converted"] = df["date"].map(lambda x: datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(x, 0)))
print df.to_string()
```

Before conversion:

```
    date
0  42369
1  42370
2  42371
3  42372
```

After:

```
    date  converted
0  42369 2015-12-31
1  42370 2016-01-01
2  42371 2016-01-02
3  42372 2016-01-03
```

Is this what you are looking for?

**Update:**

To make this work with string entries, you could either tell Pandas to treat the column as ints or floats:

```
# int
df["converted"] = df["date"].astype(int).map(lambda x: datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(x, 0)))
# float
df["converted"] = df["date"].astype(float).map(lambda x: datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(x, 0)))
```

or just cast `x` to int or float within the lambda function:

```
# int
df["converted"] = df["date"].map(lambda x: datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(x), 0)))
# float
df["converted"] = df["date"].map(lambda x: datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(float(x), 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for however my dataframe column is stored as string. How do I convert the column into intergers or floats